# Gson and Jackson caused 'no handler method found for /restendpoint' in Spring MVC

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, gson

I'm trying to add Swagger-UI in a Spring MVC Application. All requests and responses of `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` are serialized by `gson 2.6.1` (see following code.)

When I tried to integrate Swagger, I had to add following dependencies:

```
    <!-- json request -->       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--swagger-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

The Integration of Swagger worked well, but some of my requests are broken.
I receive `AbstractHandlerMethodMapping: 302 - Did not find handler method for /...`. I guess Jackson and Gson are not compatible together in this way. When I remove the jackson.core dependency, everything works fine.

In the project it's absolutey necessary to use Gson, which we also set in the application context of spring.

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="gsonBuilder" class="com.google.gson.GsonBuilder" init-method="serializeNulls" />

    <bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
        <property name="gson">
            <bean class="com.google.gson.Gson" factory-bean="gsonBuilder"
                factory-method="create" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

My Question is, does someone have an idea why jackson and gson behaves like that in the same application? Or did I forgot or miss something, to avoid that jackson convert my requests/responses?

I hope I could clarify my problem in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found out that Spring 4 automatically use `Jackson` when it's added to the classpath. In my *.xml config files I had `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`. It was causing a 2nd instance of `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` with the default `Jackson` converters without `GsonHttpMessageConverter`. This was the reason, why all my RestEndpoints didn't work properly anymore, but Swagger did.

I migrated my project to use Jackson instead of Gson and I solved my problem.